# LaTeX - Pass variable into a string

Tags: programming, strings, variable

In LaTeX I am trying to pass a variable into a line for the `\progressbar`.

If you type everything in it looks like this

```
\progressbar[linecolor=blue, filledcolor=green]{.25} \begin{picture}(0,0)\put(-35,1.5) {\tiny$25\%$} \end{picture}
```

What I'm trying to do is this

```
\newcommand{\PerComplete}{0.25}
\newcommand{\PerCompleteInt}{25}
\begin{document}
\progressbar[linecolor=blue, filledcolor=green]{.25} \begin{picture}(0,0)\put(-35,1.5) {\tiny$25\%$} \end{picture}
\progressbar[linecolor=blue, filledcolor=green]{\PerComplete} \begin{picture}(0,0)\put(-35,1.5) {\tiny$\PerCompleteInt\%$} \end{picture}
\end{document}
```

In the end, both `\progressbar`s should look the same.

How do you turn the variable of `\PerComplete` and drop into a place where numbers normally reside? Is there a convert or `.ToString()` like C#?

In case you're wondering, the end result is that I'm calling a bunch of numbers from a CSV file, which is pretty cool, but I still have the issue of trying to put the numbers into the `\progressbar` string.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx. I am not sure I get 100% what you're doing, but I think you're a tiny bit too far in the coding mindset. Is it accurate to say you're trying to draw bars that have varying lengths, depending on the values of some macros? And are you using the package `progressbar`? Maybe you can give a full MWE including  `\documentclass`, `\usepackage{}` ... etc

Comment: When I try your example (after adding `\documentclass{article}` and `\usepackage{progressbar}`) I get two identical progress bars. Are they different when you try it, and if so, which output do you get?

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I've been doing a little more testing and I think I'm going to have to give you the whole thing.  There's actually quote a bit more.  Give me 24hours and I'll post the whole thing I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: note that tex doesn't have integers or strings, it just has character tokens so there is no conversion equivalent to .ToString().

Comment: I've reposted my question with everything to it.  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/482245/possible-bug-in-passing-variables-from-csv